# Max number validation doesnt work mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Below is example of my schema model. In my model, I have eggs object assigned type Number and max is 2. The problem I am facing is that max validator doesn't work.

```
var breakfastSchema = new Schema({
eggs: {type: Number, max: 2}})
```

I use this method to increment eggs value by 1 everytime I run findByIdAndUpdate

```
$inc : { "eggs" : 1 }
```

the method works fine but it doesn't stop increment my eggs value after eggs value reaches 2 already. My eggs value can be 3 or more and I hope to have a function to stop the increment after 2 is reached. Thank you!

Comment: where and how are you updating eggs values ?

Comment: I was facing same problem yesterday and did get the solution for it... It works only when you use `$set` operator...

Comment: @Ash I see so you use $set instead of $inc to increment?